# trouble with returning multiple values from function

Tags: python

I tried researching on a way to return multiple values using single return variable. What i want to achieve is, i want the code below to act as if it is returning multiple value instead of returning a tuple

```
def my_data:
    test_data = 1, 2, 3, 4 # etc (i have a LOT of data here)
    return test_data
```

what i get is the following:

```
  td = my_data()
  print td
  output : (1,2,3,4)
```

i want the function to act as it was doing the following code:

```
return 1,2,3,4
```

Is there a way to this?

EDIT!

i'm using this with python ddt

```
@ddt
class testsuite_my_function_validations(unittest.TestCase):

    @data(my_data())
    def test_various_number(self, value):
        test_number = value
        # test the number
```

It is suppose to have four test data (1, 2, 3 and 4) instead i'm getting a tuple value and not the those four numbers. But when i

```
return 1,2,3,4
```

The output will have four testcases:

1. testcase test value 1
2. testcase test value 2
3. testcase test value 3
4. testcase test value 4

Comment: What do you mean? You have a problem with the parens?

Comment: `return 1, 2, 3, 4` is _exactly_ the same with `return test_data`.

Answer (score 6):

Returning multiple return values, like so:

```
return 1, 2, 3, 4
```

actually creates a tuple and returns it. It's exactly the same as

```
test_data = 1, 2, 3, 4
return test_data
```

In both cases, you can store the returned tuple in a variable or unpack it:

```
def my_data():
    test_data = 1, 2, 3, 4
    return test_data
a, b, c, d = my_data()
```

What you need to do is unpack the tuple in the decorator call with [`*` notation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
@ddt
class testsuite_my_function_validations(unittest.TestCase):
#         v this star here
    @data(*my_data())
    def test_various_number(self, value):
        test_number = value
        # test the number
```

Putting a `*` before the last argument of a function call unpacks that argument as a sequence and feeds the sequence elements as separate arguments to the function. In other words,

```
f(1, *(2, 3, 4))
```

is equivalent to

```
f(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Note that tuples are generally for fixed-length collections, often of inhomogenous data. If you have a large amount of data, lists are usually more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Youre question is confusing on the output you are trying to achieve but,

you could use a `list` like this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]

return list1
```

then you can acsess those values from on variable

More on [lists](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/lists.html)